# No stacktrace from core dump, no build id can be extracted from the core either

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, coredump

I have an application in production that in very unpredictable intervals (sometimes less than once a week, rarely once an hour) produces segfaults.
After first having to set it up to produce core dumps at all, I now have one. However I get no symbols at all, so it's useless.

I tried to compare build-ids with the executable that produced it, even though based on timing I pretty much am certain I have the right one, but even that cannot be extracted it seems.

```
$ eu-unstrip -n --core /path/to/core
0x7ffd56d9e000+0x1000 a6c873a47c39e0b4c46a8e56aace0675e6d58d33@0x7ffd56d9e7d0 . - linux-vdso.so.1
```

Which appears to not be the id of the [exe] I saw in examples of this.

Is there anything I can do beyond loading gdb, doing symbol-file /path/to/my/binary and having to accept that this core dump is useless to me?

EDIT:

gdb -ex where   produces what looks like a stacktrace. How is that different from running symbol-file ?

I have a few libs that I include as a source files, the rest is dynamically linked.

there is a build id in the exe according to read elf.

Comment: What is the output from: `gdb -ex where /path/to/exe /path/to/core`? Also, is your application statically linked? Does it have `BUILD_ID` note in `readelf -n /path/to/exe` ?

Comment: See my EDIT above. Seems that -ex where option seems to do something more useful.